# How can I join selectively

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Assume I have a table of vehicles:

```
v            color      col3       col4    col5   .....
car          red
train        gray
plane        white
car          blue
bike         black
(1000 more)
```

And a table with classifications:

```
prio     v        color         class
1        car      red           C1
2        car      %             F3
3        plane    %             W1
4        bike     blue          B4
5        bike     white         B8
6        bike     %             O9
```

The classifications table is small, less then 100. Only a lookup table. if necessary we can add an `id` column to the vehicles.

Now I want to add the classification to the table of vehicles. The number of rows in vehicles must not change.
The result should be:

```
v            color   class
car          red     C1
train        gray
plane        white   W1
car          blue    F3
bike         black   O9
(1000 more)
```

Now if I do

```
SELECT vehicles v
LEFT JOIN classifications c ON v.v LIKE c.v AND v.color LIKE c.color
```

I get duplicate entries because the classification match is not unique. For example a white bike matches rule 5 and 6, in this case rule 5 must be taken because it has the lower `prio`.

How can I avoid the duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated query and `LIMIT` :

```
SELECT v.*,
       (SELECT c.class FROM classifications c
        WHERE v.v like c.v AND v.color LIKE c.color
        ORDER BY c.prio LIMIT 1) AS class
FROM vehicles v
```

Although I don't understand why are you using `LIKE` if you are searching for exact an match, I assume this will be faster:

```
c.color IN(v.color,'%')
```

`LIKE` is used for partially string comparison, and its a real performance killer! So avoid it as much as you can.

Comment: Thank you, your solution seems to do it. I did not know that I can have a "select" where a column is needed. I use "like" because I want pattern matching!? What if I want 2 columns from the classifications table, lets say class1 and class? I have to repeat the correlated query for another column?

Comment: But you are not matching pattern, you are either using exact match, or equals to `%` , no need for `LIKE` @jms

Answer (score 0):

What about **distinct** ?

```
select distinct vehicles v left join classifications c
on v.v like c.v and v.color like c.color
```

I can't try right now but this should be enough to do what you are asking for...

Comment: He want the first class ordered by `prio`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This query won't work as explained in the comments below. I'll leave this answer anyway for learning purposes.

---

You can do that using aggregate functions `group by, having` and the `min` function:

```
select * from vehicles v 
            left join classifications c on v.v like c.v and v.color like c.color 
            group by v.v
            having MIN(prio)
```

This will group the results by the vehicle and then choose the row with the lowest priority.

Comment: It will force it to return one record per vehicle, but the having will happen after the group by and using an aggregate function there will likely have strange effects.

Comment: @Kickstart Since I find this really interesting could you explain this further? What strange effects could occur? I've tested the query with a small sample dataset and it worked

Comment: There are 2 main issues. Your query (excluding the HAVING clause) will bring back 1 row for each vehicle. Which row it brings back is not defined - it could be the first row, the last row or any in between, and this could change in future. Often it is the first row (not the row with the lowest number, the first row found on the table), but that is more of an accident of how MySQL goes about processing records. I have set up a quick SQL fiddle that hopefully demonstrates what can happen - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2145/1 - Note that the 2nd returned row has the higher a_number for that name

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much for the explanation! Yet again I've learnt something new today. I'll edit my answer

Comment: It is a very common misunderstanding, and numerous people get this wrong. I hate to think how much code there is in use around the world that has this issue!

Comment: As an aside, I just remembered something. Mysql has a config var of ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to prevent the use of non aggregate columns in the SELECT which are not listed in the GROUP BY clause. This defaulted to false, allowing them. As of MySQL 5.7 this config var defaults to true which will block SQL like this running. I expect that this will cause a LOT of existing code to fail.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *
FROM vehicles v
LEFT JOIN classifications c  ON
     c.prio=
       (SELECT prio FROM classifications c
        WHERE v.v like c.v AND v.color LIKE c.color
        ORDER BY c.prio LIMIT 1)`

This assumes that "prio" is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using a correlated sub query (which depending on the data can cause performance issues, as it requires MySQL to perform the sub query for every single returned row) then there are a couple of other options:-

Have a sub query that brings back the min prio for each vehicle / colour (so this sub query is performed once), and join that against the classifications table where the vehicle, colour and min prio match

```
SELECT v.v,            
    v.color,      
    c.class 
FROM vehicles v
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT v, color, MIN(prio) AS min_prio
    FROM classifications
    GROUP BY v, color
) sub0
ON v.v = sub0.v AND v.color = sub0.color
LEFT JOIN classifications c ON sub0.v = c.v AND sub0.color = c.color AND sub0.min_prio = c.prio
```

Another option is to abuse the GROUP_CONCAT function. This does assume that the class field doesn't ever contain any commas (if it might then you can use an alternative delimiter).

```
SELECT v.v,            
    v.color,      
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(c.class ORDER BY prio), ',', 1) AS class
FROM vehicles v
LEFT JOIN classifications c ON v.v = c.v AND v.color = c.color
GROUP BY v.v,            
    v.color
```